# Express clearCookie does not work as expected with options supplied

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, http, cookies

The code to set session cookie is following:

```js
                        res.cookie(newCookieName, sessionCookie, {
                            domain: getCookiesDomain(),
                            maxAge: ms('30 days'),
                            secure: true,
                            httpOnly: true,
                            sameSite: 'lax'
                        });
```

On logout we do this:

```js
function clearOneSessionCookie(res:Response, cookieName, sameSite?: 'lax'|'strict'|'none'):void {
    if (sameSite) {
        res.clearCookie(cookieName, {
            domain: getCookiesDomain(),
            maxAge: -1000,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: sameSite
        });
    } else {
        res.clearCookie(cookieName, {
            domain: getCookiesDomain(),
            maxAge: -1000,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true
        });
    }
}



    clearOneSessionCookie(res, newCookieName);
    clearOneSessionCookie(res, newCookieName, 'lax');
    clearOneSessionCookie(res, newCookieName,'strict');
    clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName);
    clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName, 'lax');
    clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName,'strict');
```

we apply all possible options of `clearOneSessionCookie` because at various stages of our project moving to different cookie name and options, we used different `sameSite` options.

I even updated to latest `express`, `cookie-parser` packages in hope for fixing that, but no effect so far.

After logout requests, following information displayed at Cookies tab at Google Chrome:

Request Cookies:

- old_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, expires = Future_Date_1, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, SameSite=[not set!]
- new_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, expires = Future_Date_2, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, SameSite=Lax

Response Cookies:

- old_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, max-age: -1000 ms, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, Same-Site: Lax
- old_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, max-age: -1000 ms, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, Same-Site: Strict
- new_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, max-age: -1000 ms, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, Same-Site: Lax
- new_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, max-age: -1000 ms, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, Same-Site: Strict

Notice that *there is now* row like

- old_cookie_name: domain = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path = /, max-age: -1000 ms, HttpOnly = yes, Secure = yes, Same-Site: [not set]

So, it seems that call

```js
clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName);
```

Does not work or not understood/recognized by browser.
This specific `set-cookie` has been ignored:

```http
set-cookie: old_cookie_name=; Max-Age=-1; Domain=www.example.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 04 Jun 2022 15:27:10 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
```

What is the best way to clear a cookie with old name and without explicit `Same-Site` value applied?

Thanks for your answers and time.

Update:
Clarification of symptoms of problem:
The `legacyCookieName` cookie with not set (no value for `SameSite` attribute) as outcome the existing users who was signed in before migration to new cookie setting are unable to sign out of website.

**Update**
Even If I made a workaround for this problem (see marked answer), if someone would offer a better *working* solution *while bounty is active*, prize is yours.

Comment: The cookies tab is only about the individual request/response, what matters is "Storage > Cookies" on the Application tab. If the cookies vanish there, you are all set. Also, when clearing a cookie, the `sameSite` does not matter. And when setting a cookie multiple times (with different `sameSite` values), only one of them survives.

Comment: I aware of that per-request nature of cookies info at network tab. May be I am not clear enough, but one of cookies (legacy cookie name with unset SameSite attribute persists and being sent on request after the logout API POST with JSON response, as part of redirect to home page of website.

Comment: it's impossible to clear httpOnly cookies with chrome in recent versions, because they want to make life hell for developers

Comment: I am not clearing cookies with chrome, I am clearing cookies server side. If you just frustrated and faced the same problem I described, try use same solution I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various tricks and tweaks to settings of legacy cookie removal API call, I came to conclusion that so far there is a single workaround for the bug being described:

1. add to responses a new cookie like `authProtocolVersion`, with value like `1`  if session involved in request processing.
2. If this cookie was already present at stage of request arrival and request must interact with session, this will update the session cookie analysis behavior to skip/ignore `legacySyssionCookie` even if it still present, and `newCookieName` not present on request arrival.
3. still sending on logout cookie cleanup during logout the `clearOneSessionCookie` calls in all possible combinations of `SameSite` - not set, `none`, `lax`, `strict`, to make sure that eventually the legacy auth cookie will be cleared as soon as that bug with cookies cleanup will be fixed at browser side.

Answer (score 0):

with the new chrome update

if you don't specify sameSite then it defaults to sameSite:'lax' by default.

so if you set a cookie with sameSite:'lax' and clearCookie with no SameSite property then the cookie gets deleted. because no samesite is = sameSite:'lax'

Comment: you can clear clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName); with clearOneSessionCookie(res, legacyCookieName, 'lax');

Comment: If this be so, the `legacyCookieName` cookie would be deleted already, and as this _does_ not happen in such way, there is some bug with implementation of this update. At Application tab still visible 2 cookies - `legacyCookieName` with unset `SameSite` and `newCookieName` with SameSite set to `Lax` after many tries to logout. Checked with Chrome Version 102.0.5005.63